# Getting started with Speech Recognition and Sphinx

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

Sphinx seems to be only real option for Java speech recognition.  Documentation is sparse and it requires a high-level of domain knowledge.  I used their example of a starting program  and it works for one file and not for another, extremely similar, file.
What is the difference?  What is the secret to getting it to work more accurately.

This file, https://www.opdsupport.com/downloads/miscellaneous/sample-audio-files/52-welcome-wav/download works, but this one, https://www.opdsupport.com/downloads/miscellaneous/sample-audio-files/49-longwelcome-wav/download does not.
I noticed that the non-working file had a different sample rate, so I used a program to convert it to 16000, but still no luck

Comment: what about mono vs stereo.  See https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialsphinx4/#streamspeechrecognizer:~:text=Please%20note%20that%20the%20audio%20for%20this%20decoding%20must%20have%20one%20of%20the%20following%20formats

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that the file that didn't work had 2 channels, so I also converted that to 1 and it still doesn't seem to work (I would attach the modified file, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that)

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Turns out you're right.  The conversion method I used didn't work.  I tried converting with SOX to 16000 sample rate and 1 channel and that fixed the problem.  Was also successfully able to convert an mp3 to a wav file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to inspect the file carefully.  According to [the docs](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialsphinx4/#streamspeechrecognizer:%7E:text=Please%20note%20that%20the%20audio%20for%20this%20decoding%20must%20have%20one%20of%20the%20following%20formats) your file must be either 8khz or 16khz and mono only.  There are many tools available to do this -- I use [audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/), but probably overkill for just a basic conversion like this.

Comment: Yes, I'm understanding more and more.  It seems like Sphinx only supports WAV file, so essentially, all files must be converted to WAV, is that right?  I basically want to be able to support any audio file.   So it sounds like you have a working system with Sphinx?   If you've got any other advice, I'd love to hear it.  Especially regarding performance and which models to use.  It seems there are other models besides what comes with it and it's unclear which is the 'best' one

Comment: It would not be uncommon to have processing pipeline that would start with a set of known file types, and then use a utility like `ffmpeg` to convert files to wav before processing.  No idea about "best" models -- it seems to me that sphinx has some "good enough" models, but also encourages you to create your own from your use cases.